# PHP query of columns with value from <select> MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to create a  list populated with the columns from a table previously selected from another  list of tables. But, I can't get the query to work.

I've appended a sample of my code that is not working. If i replace ".$search_query." with a table name it works. But, I want it to use the table selected by the user.

```
<!-- Table Select -->
<form name="myform" action="" method="post">
    <select id="parentTable_{{$index}}" name="parentTable_{{$index}}" ng-model="parentTable_$index" type="selectable" onchange="submitform();">
        <option style="display:none" value="users">select a table</option>
        <?php
        $count=1;
        $sel_query="SHOW TABLES";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sel_query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row["Tables_in_yamanagolddb"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["Tables_in_yamanagolddb"]; ?></option>
        <?php $count++; } ?>
    </select>
</form>

<!-- Index reference -->
<?php $search_query = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['parentTable_{{$index}}']); ?>

<!-- Field Select -->
<select ng-model="parentField_$index" type="selectable">
    <option style="display:none" value="">select a field</option>
    <?php
    $count=1;
    $sel_query="select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = '".$search_query."' and table_schema = 'yamanagolddb'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sel_query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row["COLUMN_NAME"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["COLUMN_NAME"]; ?></option>
    <?php $count++; } ?>
</select>

<script>
    function submitform()
    {
      document.myform.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: "my code that is not working"  But what _is_ happening? Are you getting errors? (you're _checking_ for errors, right?) If so, what are the exact error messages?  If not, how does the actual result/behavior differ from the desired one?

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: Have you tried `echo $sel_query;` to see if the parameter is being filled in correctly?

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: I'm assuming that your expecting to change a select option with a list of tables and this to then automagically fill in the list of fields of that table.  You will need to do something like on change of selecting the table, an AJAX call to list the columns and populate the second select.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding when the parts of this code are going to run.  You might get a better grasp if you put your form-handling code into a different file, or better yet, use an MVC framework.

Comment: You need to submit the first form before you can retrieve the value of the POST parameters to create the second `<select>`. If you want this to be done without submitting the form, you'll need to use AJAX.

Comment: Error message is "Notice: undefined index: parentTable_0 in..."